# HTML5 Bootstrap Single Page - Vert Centering <section>'s

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, templates

Hello all and thanks for the input.

I've looked at a number of templates but haven't felt that I've found a clean way of presenting vertically centered content of a "section" on single page layouts. I am referring to the entire section space space here, not the elements within.

The desired effect is to limit the viewable content to sections at a time and use a scroll to move to the next section on the single page ... easy enough with easing.js.

So for a psuedo markup there would be something like

```
<section id="topic1"
    <random element>
    <random element>
</section>

... Some space added to ensure no overlap of sections are viewed here ...
... e.g. margin-top: 100px or 10%

<section id="topic2"
    <random element>
    <random element>
    <random element>
    <random element>
</section>

... Some space added ...
... e.g. margin-top: 100px

...etc
```

As the browser moves to each section (by anchors) each one would be shown with " empty space" and it delivers a nice effect. The challenge is to always have the sections vertically centered as we change devices in a 'responsive' type approach. I've also found some inconsistencies with Internet Explorer.  Understandably at certain screen sizes (say table landscape height and phones) this becomes impossible and scrolling will be necessary.

Any thoughts on a CSS approach to implement this cleanly would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking it is likely a JQuery call to get the current section height and the current viewport height. If the section > viewport, load at the top otherwise calculate the middle of the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using a wrap and using the css properties `display:table` and `display:table-cell` together with `vertical-align:middle`

HTML markup with your needed wrap:

```
<section id="topic1">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div> aaaa</div>
        <div> aaaa</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Needed css:

```
section{
    display:table;
    height:220px;
    background: #ccc;
    width:100%;
}
.wrap{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Living demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hvLx3/)

Using `line-height` is a more simple method but you need to know the `height` of the section.

You can find more ways about how to accomplish it [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/).

Comment: A quick thank you Alvaro - I'll give it some review. I am concerned, however, that setting the static height to 220px will cause issues across being responsive and that is one of the things I am trying to avoid.  I do not want to define section heights statically.

Comment: It was just for the example. You can set it with percentages if you prefer, it will work the same way.

Comment: After additional research the use of tables is indeed the right way to go and it does support percentages of both width and height at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways to can use the Bootstrap markup to achieve what you are looking for.  Here is one example:

```
.space {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

<section class="container space">
  <div id="scroll-to" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <p class="text-center"><a href="#">Random Elements</a></p>
      <p class="text-center"><a href="#">Random Elements</a></p>
      <p class="text-center"><a href="#">Random Elements</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="container space">
  <div id="scroll-to" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <p class="text-center"><a href="#">Random Elements</a></p>
      <p class="text-center"><a href="#">Random Elements</a></p>
      <p class="text-center"><a href="#">Random Elements</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I would try and concentrate on the offset classes and look at using .center-block and .center-text.  Center-block will align your elements center, and center-text will do the same for text.  This will keep you from bloating your css and keep everything predictable for responsive design.

Hope this helps.